# How to create python tkinter canvas objects named with variable and keep this link to reconfigure the object?

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter

It's my first post so I want to thanks the community. I never had to ask my own question until now because of your experience.

Here is my question:

- If you look the exemple script below, you see that I create objects in a tKinter canvas using a loop.
- In this loop, i create variable called 'name'and value is 'objectx'
- I try to draw objects (here text objects) using this variable 'name'.

Doing this i was hopping that, using the 'name' variable value, i'll be able to, for exemple, delete/configure/move the objects. But no. My object remains linked to 'name' and not 'objectx'. Python returns me 'NameError: name 'object2' is not defined'

Does someone know a solution for me to build a link between an canvas object and keep it to interact with it?

Many thanks

```
import tkinter as tk

def popup(event):
    print('Got object click', event.x, event.y)
    print(event.widget.find_closest(event.x, event.y))
    lvl01 = tk.Toplevel(bd = 1, bg = 'black')
    time.sleep(2)
    print('2sec')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()

    can = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 400)
    can.pack()

    x = 0
    while x < 10:
        x = x + 1
        name = "object" + str(x)
        print(name)
        name = can.create_text(x * 30, x * 30, text = 'hello')

    can.delete(object2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You think you're binding a variable named object2 (or other number) to can.create_text.

What you're actually doing is first binding a variable called name to be a string 'object2', then you re-bind it to the return value of the can.create_text call.

There is more than one way to achieve the first result, but the one that springs to mind in this case that would allow quick access by name is to make a dict like so:

```
windows = {}
x = 0
while x < 10:
    x = x + 1
    name = "object" + str(x)
    print(name)
    windows[name] = can.create_text(x * 30, x * 30, text = 'hello')

can.delete(windows[object2])
```

Comment: that's what i was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can't create variable names like that. This code:

```
name = "object" + str(x)
name = can.create_text(x * 30, x * 30, text = 'hello')
```

creates a string, binds it to the name `name`, and then immediately overwrites it with the ID of the Canvas text object.

But you could store your Canvas text objects in a dictionary, using the name as the key.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
can = tk.Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 400)
can.pack()

objects = {}
for x in range(1, 11):
    sx = str(x)
    name = "object" + sx
    print(name)
    objects[name] = can.create_text(x * 30, x * 30, text = 'hello' + sx)

can.delete(objects["object2"])
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You gave me the same solution in the same time but still the good one. Thank you